# What is this url mean, "/h/xxx.html" of my website?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

In Google Analytics I found a page which I did not create.

The full url is http://youngzy.com/h/3668354.html.

When I open it, it looks like the latest  posts recently.
But who make it?
Does it generate automatically ?

Why, Where and How?
Any experience? Thanks.

**I'm using WordPress.org**

Comment: Any plugin that might be creating it in the backend or a wordpress theme functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I guess so. And I wanna a determinate answer.

Comment: You would need to add more info to your question for someone to find a definite answer. This is because of too many variables involved with WP installations.

Comment: I've flagged this as off-topic, because this is more of a usage question related to WordPress, rather than about programming. You may want to ask a similar question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: @AnkDasCo Plugins or something else?

Comment: @N.Wouda Thanks. I though even a plugin it's related to programming. Maybe I should ask in a WordPress forum.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found this to be annoying referral spam designed to get you to visit their website. I filtered my report by “Hostname” and found all the visits are from one of 5 domains which all redirect to a website with a “free" SEO report: https://semalt.com/?ref=seocheckupx.  Just more obnoxious spam tactic by an unreputable SEO firm - Semalt.

Here's a good article about referral spam from Semalt and how to filter them out of your analytics: https://www.kymodo.com.au/what-is-semalt-doing-on-your-website/